# Google Sheets formulas: how to return where a MIN or MAX values within a range were found?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to find a way to get the index of a cell where the value was found; more specifically, I want to return the numerical value of the row where it was found, as I need the number to be used in some calculation.

I tried using "LOOKUP" with the returned MIN or MAX value — but that for some reason returns the no match was found.

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and show your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: The perceived need to find a row number often suggests that you in the end want to locate some _value_ as well, rather than just finding the row number. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: @doubleunary The value I want is the value of row where the MIN or MAX values are. The numerical content of the cells is already available through the simple =MIN() and =MAX() formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    split( 
      flatten( row(A2:F) & "→" & A2:F ), 
      "→", false, true 
    ), 
    "select Col1 where Col2 = " & max(A2:F), 0 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: That worked! But I would like to know what each component of the formula does. Care to explain? Thank you.

Comment: See [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343), [split()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) and [flatten()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761). An `arrayformula()` wrapper lets you evaluate a formula over a range of cells rather than a single cell, returning multiple results automatically. It is required here primarily to make the `&` operator work over arrays.

Comment: I assume it makes an array of two columns, one with numbers and one with the values and this syntax tells it somehow to return the number in column 1 when the adjacent cell in column 2 has the result for MAX or MIN? I'm not familiar with these formulas other than ARRAYFORMULA(), and I suppose Google's explanations could be formulated more clearly.

Comment: That is correct.